# CF: Cell STATUS + Cell DATE compared to NOW(DATE) = Colour

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, conditional-formatting

If the status in cell $D5 is "AWAITING FEEDBACK" I want to compare the DATE in cell $H5 against TODAYS DATE and CONDITIONAL FORMAT cell $H5 using the data bars formatting (colour to transparent).

If the date is two weeks away then a small colour bar is used, but if the date is today then it would use the longest colour bar (virtually full). These would be my highest and lowest parameters.

A horrible example of how I thought it might look...

```
=If($D..="Awaiting feedback",(Now(DAYS($H..)+14)). SHORTEST COLOUR BAR
=If($D..="Awaiting feedback",(Now(DAYS($H..))) LONGEST COLOUR BAR
```

...apologies if I made anyone's eyes bleed.

Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two parts to this solution, and an alternative which I would probably prefer.

Firstly, you can't do all that complicated formula in the data bar directly, so don't try.

Go to the cells with the due dates in them and apply a standard data bar. 
Now go to conditional formatting > manage rules > select the rule for the data bar and go to edit rule.
Instead of having the shortest bar for the lowest value and longest for the highest, choose to do shortest for a specified number (or formula, it won't matter). For the number put in =TODAY()+14.
Now your shortest bars will be for any dates 14 days in the future or later.

For the longest bar, again do number or formula and put in simply =TODAY(), so any dates of today or earlier will have the longest bars.

Click OK and Apply. Now your bars should be right, but they will also be showing up for any status rows.

The clever bit (IMHO): now select the same cells, and add a new conditional format rule, based on a formula:
=$D2<>"Awaiting Feedback"  (you don't need any messy IFs or anything, just a straight statement which is either True or False)

You don't need any formatting, just leave it, OK it. In the Rules Manager window make sure this new rule comes above your data bars rule (move it with the up arrows if necessary) and *tick the box for "Stop if True"*

Now, if the row is not an awaiting feedback row, that rule is true, and it stops processing any more rules (for the same affected cells, other independent rules are fine). For Awaiting Feedback ones, you get your data bars, with the longest being the most urgent.

OK. Reality check.

I would not do this unless I really had to. 
I would use a helper column (eg G) with a formula to check for the status, and if it was one I wanted to flag I would put in there the relevant value for the due date - today(). 
Then use standard data bars on those values (maybe switch longest and shortest so today's jobs have longer bars, no formulas needed for that). Use the tick box on the rule to show the bar only so the numbers themselves go away.
I would prefer this so I could actually use a different rule (maybe just a single colour fill) for anything which is already past due date to make it even more important than things due today.

You could do this on the date cells but the more formatting you apply the harder you make it to actually read the dates, so a helper column is useful here, and makes the conditional formattig part more 'normal'

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working on this with someone in another forum, and thought I would leave it here so you could see what we're working on - and the part that I'm now stuck on.

(aali dad from utter access said)

Select your data in Column D and H go to Format>> Conditional Formatting. Select Condition 1 Formula is:

```
=IF($D2="Awaiting Feedback",IF($H2>TODAY()+14,TRUE,FALSE),FALSE)
```

and Format the cell color as you wish. And then Add a second condition with this Formula =
Quote:

```
=IF($D2="Awaiting Feedback",IF($H2=TODAY(),TRUE,FALSE),FALSE)
```

I'm now stuck on the Microsoft message: "You cannot use relative references in Conditonal Formatting criteria for color scales, data bars, and icon sets".

I'm struggling with the message now - I've tried using the whole range $D2:$D126, which it lets me do but I don't see a result.

Anyway thought I would keep you posted - in case it gives you inspiration.

Thanks
Mike.

Comment: What is causing the problem there is that for colour scales, data bars and icon sets there is no true / false - instead it looks for high and low values to ge a range between them. The bars are not on or off, they are simply longer or shorter. The error message is very poor really, but you are going about this the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update. I don't think it can be done...at the moment. Something abut conditional formatting not recognising the certain cell references.

I've closed this question.

Comment: Sorry I did not see your question originally. Of course this can be done, you just have to think outside the box. See my answer below, and if you find it works, give me that "mark as answer" instead of your own update. Thanks!